# consulta crystal reports c# EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, crystal-reports

Estuve viendo algunos ejemplos sobre como pasar parametros a un crystal report que está enlazado con un SP, vi que en varios de estos ejemplos utilizan una url "hardcodeada" lo cual no me parece una solución muy viable para cuando se utilice en distintas máquinas..  hay alguna forma de hacer un load "generico"?

```
        ReportDocument reporte = new ReportDocument();
        ParameterField Pf = new ParameterField();
        ParameterDiscreteValue Pv = new ParameterDiscreteValue();
        ParameterFields Pfs = new ParameterFields();
        Pf.Name = "@idReceta";
        Pv.Value = idEntidad;
        Pf.CurrentValues.Add(Pv);
        Pfs.Add(Pf);
        crystalReportViewer1.ParameterFieldInfo = Pfs;
        reporte.Load(@"C:\Direcciones\Reportes\ReportesRecetas.rpt");
        crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = reporte;
```

intenté con esto pero no me funciona:

```
            reporte.Load(@"..\Reportes\ReportesRecetas.rpt");
```

siendo que mi formulario está en una carpeta "hermana" de Reportes, es decir que con ir a la carpeta anterior desde mi form deberia poder acceder a "Reportes" de la forma en que lo hice..

saludos

Comment: Separa la extraccion de datos con lo que es la fuente de tu reporte, ahora en tu reporte intenta solo mostrar pocos datos ya cuando lo hayas conseguido agrega mas elementos, asi tendras menos complicaciones. Reescribe tu pregunta con dudas puntuales.

Comment: ahi edito mejor con lo que quiero

Answer (score 0):

deberias usar una url relativa desde donde está ejecutandose tu actual proyecto (donde queda el exe compilado), usualmente si estas en modo debug es .bin/debug/tuproyecto.exe o en modo release es .bin/release/tuproyecto.exe, y cuando lo copies a una carpeta para "produccion", te quedara en cualquier ubicacion, con una carpeta "Reportes" dentro... (debes asegurarte que los archivos .rpt del proyecto tengan como propiedad del mismo "Copiar siempre" para que al compilar queden en dichas carpetas de bin/debug o bin/release copiadas)

por lo que para que tome una carpeta de reportes desde cualquier ubicacion relativa al exe, lo mejor es usar como base de la url un metodo que traiga dicha carpeta, por ejemplo:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory
```

por lo que si tu reporte esta en una subcarpeta "Reportes" desde el ejecutable, seria algo asi como

```
var pathReporte = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\Reportes\ReportesRecetas.rpt"
```